# Empty default option on select Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

What I'm trying to do is Angular to get the value from an variable and put it on the first option, while the others below will be static. Angular is getting the data but the first option is always blank.

**HTML**

```
<select [(ngModel)]="sub_planning">
<option value="data[0].value" >{{data[0].name}}</option>
<option *ngFor="let c of subdimension" [ngValue]="c.value">{{c.name}}</option>
</select>
```

**TS**

```
sub_planning = '0';
subdimension = [{'name': 'oneabc','value': 1 },
  {'name': 'twoabc','value': 2}];
```

I found some answers on the internet but it's on Angular 2 and it does't seems to work for Angular 4

Comment: what is data here?

Comment: Are you sure, that `data[0].name` exists? Please, show us your `data` variable

Comment: Yes, the data is there on the dropdown, I'm getting it from another API but this is not the problem. The problem is that this data is showing as the second option and not as default. The default option is blank.

Comment: Can you try to replace by  value="" ?

Comment: @Vega I tried, didn't worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of invalid datatypes,

```
sub_planning = 1
```

Note: Type of number.

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/friZUjDr9HRTtpREAysl?p=preview)**